# Using fadeIn / fadeOut with Scroll Up For Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the jQuery script "Scroll Up for Menu" by David Simpson, ([Github Link](http://github.com/dvdsmpsn/scroll-up-for-menu)) and I am trying to get it so that it uses `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`, so that when you scroll it fades out, and when you scroll back up the nav fade back in. I can't seem to figure out where to add it. Is it better to add an easing event to the nav div (in this case `#top`) or a `fadeIn` within the script?

**JS**

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

var pluginName = 'scrollUpMenu';
var defaults = {
        waitTime: 100,
        transitionTime: 550,
        menuCss: { 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0'},
        showDelta: 0
};

var lastScrollTop = 0;
var $header;
var timer;
var pixelsFromTheTop;

// The actual plugin constructor
function Plugin ( element, options ) {
    this.element = element;
    this.settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this.init();
}

Plugin.prototype = {
    init: function () {

        var self = this;
        $header = $(this.element);
        $header.css(self.settings.menuCss);
        pixelsFromTheTop = $header.height();

        // $header.next().css({ 'margin-top': pixelsFromTheTop });

        $(window).bind('scroll',function () {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                self.refresh(self.settings);
            }, self.settings.waitTime );
        });
    },
    refresh: function (settings) {
        // Stopped scrolling, do stuff...
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 
        var change = lastScrollTop - scrollTop;

        if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop && scrollTop > pixelsFromTheTop){ // ensure that the header doesnt disappear too early
            // downscroll
            $header.slideUp(settings.transitionTime);
        } else {
            // upscroll
            if ( change > settings.showDelta ) {
                $header.slideDown(settings.transitionTime);
            }
        }
        lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
    }
};

$.fn[ pluginName ] = function ( options ) {
    return this.each(function() {
            if ( !$.data( this, 'plugin_' + pluginName ) ) {
                    $.data( this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
            }
    });
};
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

**HTML**

```
$(function() {          
        $('#top').scrollUpMenu({'transitionTime': 100});  
    });
```

**JSFiddle** 
https://jsfiddle.net/09qxdx43/2/

Comment: can you put it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: **jsfiddle here:**  https://jsfiddle.net/09qxdx43/2/

Comment: I'm wondering if I need to add it to the function on the main page...

Answer (score 0):

Solved! fadeIn/fadeOut instead of slideUp

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    var pluginName = "scrollUpMenu";
    var defaults = {
            waitTime: 20,
            transitionTime: 300,
            menuCss: { 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0'}
    };

    var lastScrollTop = 0;              
    var $header;
    var timer;
    var pixelsFromTheTop;

    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Plugin ( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;
        this.settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {
        init: function () {

            var self = this;
            $header = $(this.element);
            $header.css(self.settings.menuCss);
            pixelsFromTheTop = $header.height();

            $header.next().css({ 'margin-top': pixelsFromTheTop });

            $(window).bind('scroll',function () {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    self.refresh(self.settings) 
                }, self.settings.waitTime );
            });
        },
        refresh: function (settings) { 
            // Stopped scrolling, do stuff...                           
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop && scrollTop > pixelsFromTheTop){ // ensure that the header doesnt disappear too early
                // downscroll
                $header.fadeOut(settings.transitionTime);
            } else {
                // upscroll
                $header.fadeIn(settings.transitionTime);
            }
            lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
        }
    };

    $.fn[ pluginName ] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function() {
                if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
                        $.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
                }
        });
    };

})( jQuery, window, document );
```